# Not able to get google analytics client ID

Tags: google-analytics

For my wordpress blog I've installed google analytics plug-in.
In order to activate it, user-id and secret are requested to me.
I've watched many tutorials to learn how to do it. But that's a problem. In every tutorial, the drop-down menu to the left is different to mine. What could I do?
Best regards

[image]

second Image

[image]

Comment: Wrong terminology, clientId is something different in GA (identifies a unique visitor to your website). I don't read Italian (?), but from the screenshot it looks like you want an API key (which you should get from the credentials section of the menu in the second screenshot).

Comment: I don't have the credential menu in my GA (first screenshot). TNX